# using sqlcipher to encrypt already existing database and opening it on android

Tags: android, encryption, sqlcipher

I encrypted my already existing sqlite database using following method given on sqlcipher documentation

```
$ ./sqlite3 plaintext.db 
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.db' AS encrypted KEY 'testkey'; 
sqlite> SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted'); 
sqlite> DETACH DATABASE encrypted;
```

this works and produces an encrypted database with comparable memory size like original.
and then I tried to access the database on my android application using

> SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(myDatabasePath, "testkey", null);

querying on db instance shows that there are no existing tables in the database. 
I am able to create new tables as well as add rows to them and read them but I can't see my old existing tables. I carefully followed the guidelines given in the sqlcipher documentation of changing imports.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you are accessing the right database *file*? Remember that `openOrCreateDatabase()` will create an empty database if you try accessing one by name that does not already exist.

Comment: yup, this time I ran the app on emulator and pulled the created database and it was the same database.

Comment: decrypted the pulled database. found to contain one extra table which I created later while using the app + the originally existing tables but the same app is not able to access these other tables while running. weird

Comment: Are you bundling the exported database in the assets directory of your application?

Comment: Hi, ya I have the exported database as zipped file in assets directory.