# Android Database Encryption to Protect Data & Model

Tags: android, database, encryption

I ship a database with my app, and I would like to protect the data model from others peeking inside. Basically I dont want anyone opening the db file besides the app itself.

My research has led me to SQLCipher for Android:
https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/

However some of the posts online say that encrypting DB will not prevent someone from opening it, as an attacker can easily look up the key:
[Android How to use SqlCipher with pre-bundled Sqllite Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467005/android-how-to-use-sqlcipher-with-pre-bundled-sqllite-database)

To me if the key can be looked up then the point of encrypting a shipped db is pointless as it does not offer protection.

My question is:

Is SQLCipher the right approach to encrypt the DB in order to protect its data & model from attackers?

Comment: slqcipher uses AES algorithm to encrypt the data, you can implement it by yourself with more control on that

Comment: Do you mean taking the route of encrypting / decrypting column values manually?

Comment: yse, that is how sqlcipher works